# What is the redacted lyric in Portal 2's credits?

Tags: portal-2

In the credits song "Want You Gone" of Portal 2, there is one line where the text is `[REDACTED]`. The lyric is either "I'll stop feeling so *bad*" or "I'll stop feeling so *glad*", but even after listening multiple times I still can't tell which one.

Can anyone provide evidence for which one it is? Or is it ambiguous on purpose, so you don't know whether GLaDOS loves you or not at the end?

Comment: After listening a few more times, it sounds more like "glad" to me. Now that I think of it, maybe she said "GLaD".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The lyric is "I'll stop feeling so bad". The reason it is redacted in the first place, is because GLaDOS is, in her own way, admitting she has grown fond of Chell. Redacting it prevents that admission of momentary weakness.

If she was happy Chell was gone, there would have been no need to redact the lyric.

I *think* this song is captioned if you've turned on subtitles, which will confirm the above.

Comment: I can confirm that if you have captioning on then you will be able to read the redacted lyrics.

Comment: Not entirely true, the captioning tell you "bad". but GLaDOS tells us "GLaD". It's an in-game joke

Comment: GLaD makes no sense. The lyric is "bad".

Comment: Ellen McLain (the voice of GLaDOS) sang the song twice at Anime Midwest 2011, and the lyric was "bad": http://youtu.be/ZVgXSB4_sTU and http://youtu.be/9c8QJB5kfPs

Answer (score 4):

I actually believe the following:

GLaDOS says "I'll stop feeling so GLaD."
The captions say "I'll stop feeling so bad."
The monitor tells us [REDACTED]

This is only to mess around with the player, obviously GLaDOS doesn't want to show her weakness of feeling bad for what she did and tells the player she is GLaD instead of feeling bad. However, that's just her version of the song, the official lyrics are "I'll stop feeling so bad".

That's probably the joke of the song, that line of the song is shown in 3 different ways to the player, all meaning a totally different thing. It wasn't "REDACTED" for no reason of course...

Comment: "GLaDOS says "I'll stop feeling so GLaD." No, she says "I'll stop feeling so bad."  You can [listen to the song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVVZaZ8yO6o) and hear it.

Comment: When I listen to it, I hear either "GLaD" or maybe a combination of both "GLaD" and "bad" (i.e. with the two sounds overlaid). I can't make myself hear "bad".

Answer (score 1):

In the first end song, Still Alive, you can see they use the lyric "GLaD" instead of "glad", and in Want you gone they add the same signature, but in audio form (I'll stop feeling so GLaD).

You can quite clearly hear the word glad in the audio, it's somewhat of an easter egg for players of the original Portal :)

Answer (score 1):

It's "I'll stop feeling so bad" because if you can translate what the turrets are singing, they refer to "my little girl" quite a few times.